# Showing XML layout file design through an activity on android app

Tags: android, xml, view, xml-parsing, layout-inflater

How can I show a layout.xml design on an activity? Say If I have a layout.xml file on external storage on android. If I want to show the full design of layout.xml file on some specific view group (say linear or relative layout) inside my activity of android app at runtime. If anyone can provide example to show any kind of layout.xml file's design on an activity.

Comment: Sorry, but there is no support for that in Android. It is possible that somebody has a library for it.

Comment: Okay.. thanks for describing!

Comment: this might be possible but will be a tedious process. for example: AIDE Android App on PlayStore has this feature.

Comment: Yes you are right, but unfortunately AIDE is not open source.. do suggest me if you know any other apps....Thanks